# Sum of roots for a even function and slope being 0?

Tags: calculus, functions, rolles-theorem, even-and-odd-functions

High school senior and was helping my friend with Rolle's theorem and came across this neat point.

Given $f(x)$ is a continuous and differentiable function, and $f(-x)=f(x)$. Additionally, $f(x)=0$ must occur at least twice. Finding the mean of the $x$ values of any two consecutive roots and evaluating it in the function will give you exactly where $f'(x)=0$. I’m not sure, but I think if you take the arithmetic mean of the $x$ values of any two roots for an even function, plugging in this value will go a slope of zero?

Any feedback would be awesome!

Comment: I think you should first think thoroughly about this question... Generally, it is impossible to finding the mean of two consecutive roots that you can get a point with derivative zero. Rolle's theorem Only guarantee that there is a point with derivative zero between two roots, But there is no guarantee of. it is to be the mean. One guarantee for the differentiable even function is that the zero point has derivative zero. Other points has no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x)=x^4-5x^2+4=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)$$ is even. The zeros $x=1$ and $x=2$ are "consecutive" and have an arithmetic mean of $\bar x={3\over 2}$.

However, $f'\left({3\over 2}\right)=-{3\over 2}\neq 0.$

[image]

Comment: Neat, I guess the functions I looked on Desmos worked out! Would this hold true if instead you looked  at the zeroes closest to the origin?

Comment: Additionally, you may have interpreted my answer incorrectly sorry how it was worded. If you take x=3/2 and evaluate in the function in your case y= -2.18175. At this y value, the  slope is zero. I mean taking your arithmetic mean of roots, and using that x value to evaluate in your function. At that y value, f’(x)=0. So using your example, I guess this “reasoning” is valid. I would really appreciate feedback! I have no one else to talk to about this lol.

Comment: In reality, this is also taking motivation from the vertex of a parabola being the sum of your two roots.This is obviously a point  when plugged in to your function the slope is zero. I am taking this general point but extending to the branch of even functions.

Comment: @MoriSchacter The slope is not zero at that point. The slope at that point is the slope of the blue tangent line in the picture, which is $-3/2$